# How to integrate Avangate webservice?

Tags: php

I need some source code or example to integrate Avangate webservices with PHP application.

Does anybody have sample source code or can someone help me on how to integrate its api using php.

I had gone through its document but its lengthy and bit confusing. I need some guidance who have worked on this.

- How to add new products. Can i add it from control panel or need to use it's API.
- How to parse the notification data received as a response from avangate.

Comment: What kind of research have You done so far? What have You tried? It's really broad question, You should do some research and narrow it down first.

Comment: I also realized the same, I have just edited my question. Hope this give some clear picture of my requirement.